# How to use apply with a function that required 2 parameters

Tags: r, function, apply

I looked at the existing posts but could not get a clear answer... I have a data frame and I would like to modify each data by a calculation that takes into account the min and max of each lines.

I would like to use apply associated to a function:

```
sc=function(x,seg) {(x-seg[2])*100/(seg[1]-seg[2])}
```

or

```
sc=function(x,a,b) {(x-b)*100/(a-b)}
```

where x is a line of the data frame and seg=c(a,b) calculated as follow

```
d=dim(data) ## data is my dataframe
for (i in (1:d[1]))  ## the calculation has to be done for each line, according
                     ## the min and max of the specific line   
{
seg=c(max(data[i,]),min(data[i,]))
data[i,]=apply(data[i,],1,sc) 
return(data)
}
```

This does not work, obviously, because I do not know how to tell apply that it needs to take into account more than one parameter...

There is probably a R function that does this specific calculation, but since I am a R beginner, I would really appreciate to understand how to create such coding.

Thanks for the help!

Stéphane

**Update:**
Here is what I found for a solution, but it does not sound completely logical to me...

```
for (i in (1:d[1])) {
t=apply(data,2,sc,seg=range(data[i,]))
data[i,]=t[i,] }
```

Comment: See the examples in `?apply`. In particular, `apply(x, 1, cave,  c1 = "x1", c2 = c("x1","x2"))`

Comment: thanks for your comment. Yes I saw that in the help, but it is not very explicit... I tried: `data[i,]=apply(data[i,],1,sc,seg=range(data[i,])` but I have this error message: `Erreur dans apply(data[i, ], 1, sc, seg = range(data[i, ])) : 
  dim(X) must have a positive length`

Answer (score 0):

The third parameter you pass to apply should be a function. Also, there's no reason to loop when you use apply.

```
apply(d,1,function(x) c(min(x), max(x)))
```

will return a 2-row matrix with the min and max values for each row. Although there is a build in function to get min/max called `range

```
apply(d,1,range)
```